Interchanging infimum in Chernoff bound
Suppose $\inf_{\lambda \geq 0} f(\lambda) = c > -\infty$ exists and $g$ satisfies $g (\inf_{\lambda \geq 0} f(\lambda)) = g(c) = \inf_{\lambda \geq 0} g(f(\lambda))$, what can be said about $g$?
This thought arose while reviewing the derivation of the Chernoff bound. If we let $\phi_Z(\lambda) = \log Ee^{\lambda Z}$ for random variable $Z$, we have
$$
\Pr[Z \geq t] \leq \inf_{\lambda \geq 0} Ee^{\lambda(Z - t)}, 
$$
and subsequent analysis is on $\phi_Z^*(t) = \sup_{\lambda \geq 0} (\lambda t - \phi_Z(\lambda))$, to where we get
$$
\Pr[Z \geq t] \leq e^{-\phi_Z^*(t)},
$$
which clearly uses the fact that $\inf_{\lambda \geq 0} \exp(\phi_Z(\lambda) - \lambda t) \leq \exp(\inf_{\lambda \geq 0} (\phi_Z(\lambda) - \lambda t))$, which is the obvious direction (take $g(x) = e^x$ and $f(\lambda) = \phi_Z(\lambda) - \lambda t$ for some fixed $t$.)
However, in this case, the other direction holds as well (i.e., equality). Suppose for the sake of contradiction that
$$
\inf_{\lambda \geq 0} \exp(f(\lambda)) < c < \exp(\inf_{\lambda \geq 0} f(\lambda)),
$$
that is the term is strictly smaller. Then, the first inequality says some $\lambda$ fulfills $\exp(f(\lambda)) < c$ while the other says all $\lambda$ have $f(x) >\log c$, which is ridiculous, thus we have equality.
What exact property of $e^x$ causes this? It seems to be that monotonically increasing is doing the heavy lifting here, but is it necessary?
